# First TextBox doesnt show cursor and cannot type anything if used tab button in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, tabindex

I have a textbox first, then password box, then confirm password box. If i use just tab to move between these boxes, then first textbox doesnt allow me to type anything as well as i cant see any cursor on it. But for the next password and confirm passoword i can use tab to switch, type and cursor is also visible. I want the first textbox to be able to work as same as password box. I use xaml. Here is the code. Any help would be useful. Thank you. PS: dont work about "****" you see in code.

```
TextBox x:Name="txtUsername"
                    TabIndex="1"
                         x:Uid="*****"
                         Tag="Username"
                     Style="{DynamicResource placeHolderMandatory}"
                         ctrl:PlaceHolderHelper.PlaceHolderText="Username *"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                     Focusable="False"
                     IsTabStop="False"
                     KeyUp="credentialKeyUp" 
          Width="402"  Margin="5,5,5.4,25"  />

<PasswordBox x:Name="newPassword"
          x:Uid="****"
           TabIndex="2"
                         KeyUp="credentialKeyUp"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="402"  Margin="5,5,5.4,25" 
                         ctrl:PasswordPlaceHolderHelper.PlaceHolderText="Password     (must be atleast 8 characters in length)" 
                         ctrl:PasswordPlaceHolderHelper.MandatoryPlaceHolderText="Password *" 
                         Style="{DynamicResource PasswordPlaceHolder}"/>

<PasswordBox x:Name="confirmPassword" 
          x:Uid="*****"
          TabIndex="3"
          VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         KeyUp="credentialKeyUp"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="402"  Margin="5,5,5.4,25" 
                         ctrl:PasswordPlaceHolderHelper.PlaceHolderText="Confirm Password"
                         ctrl:PasswordPlaceHolderHelper.MandatoryPlaceHolderText="Confirm Password *" 
                         Style="{DynamicResource PasswordPlaceHolder}" />
```

and the style code is:
textbox style code:

```
<Style x:Key="placeHolderMandatory" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text,
                                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                                Mode=TwoWay,
                                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                 x:Name="textSource" 
                                 Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" IsTabStop="False" Focusable="True"
                                 Background="Transparent" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                 Panel.ZIndex="3" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" MaxLength="{TemplateBinding MaxLength}"
                                 Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" TabIndex="{TemplateBinding TabIndex}" />

                        <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                                 BorderBrush="{DynamicResource TextBoxBorderColorBrush}"  IsReadOnly="True" IsTabStop="False"
                                 Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"  VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                 FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Panel.ZIndex="2"  TabIndex="500">
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference textSource}}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray"/>
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                        <TextBox Text="{TemplateBinding local:PlaceHolderHelper.PlaceHolderText}"  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}"
                                 Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Panel.ZIndex="1"  Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" IsReadOnly="True" IsTabStop="False"
                                 BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" TabIndex="501">
                            <TextBox.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, Source={x:Reference textSource}}" Value="">
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                                            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </TextBox.Style>
                        </TextBox>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove the `Focusable="False"` as well as the  `IsTabStop="False"` from the first input. Then it should work (at least it did for me)

The `Focusable="False"` stops the field from gaining focus at all (also not by pressing tab) while the `IsTabStop="False"` stops you from selecting it using tab.

Edit: I think making the foreground transparent hides the cursor, so remove that line in your style if you want the cursor to show.

Edit 2: you can use this style to implement placeholder text instead:

```
<Style x:Key="PlaceholderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Tag}"/>
            </Trigger>

        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

With this code, just write the placeholder text in the Tag (like you did) and you are good to go. You can of course add other setters to the style and to the trigger (for example in order to make the placeholder grey, but the normal text transparent).

Comment: It partially works. It however allows me to type in the Textbox, but the cursor is not visible when it is focused on that box

Comment: I think it might be because you set the foreground color of the upper text box to transparent (in your style) if you remove that line it shoud work fine

Comment: No, that transparent value is the textbox says "username" and that will be transparent when i type something. If i remove that, then, even though i type something into textbox, that "username" will still be there.

Comment: Have you tried removing it? This does indeed mean you need to rewrite your solution for placeholders. A (way cleaner in my opinion, no need to rewrite the template) solution would be storing the placeholder in text and when the textbox is not in focus, set the text property equal to the tag property